# If Boromir hadn't died, would they have gone to Gondor and not Rohan?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

With Boromir's death in "The Fellowship of the Ring" is it safe to say that after hunting down the Uruk-hai they would have all gone to Gondor instead of Rohan if he had survived? If this did happen would they have completely forsaken Rohan and the remaining party wouldn't have seen Gandalf reborn as the White?

Comment: Going to Rohan had nothing to do with Boromir's death. Aragorn had said he wanted to go to Minas Tirith, even after Boromir's death. But of course, they had to save the hobbits first

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think so, with Frodo and Sam departing with the Ring, Aragorn would still have led the remaining members of the fellowship to save Merry and Pippen. That course of action, of course, leads them into Fangorn and to an encounter with Gandalf the White. Keep in mind, too, that Boromir seems repentant after trying to get the ring, so I don't really seem him trying to stir the company to Gondor against Gandalf's and Aragorn's wishes.

Your suggestion might be plausible IF Merry and Pippen aren't kidnapped. That's what leads them to Rohan and to an encounter with Gandalf the White.

Comment: Boromir also might well have seen the advantage to Gondor in saving Rohan from Saruman, so that the riders could reinforce them when Sauron struck.